# Script or CSS to bold all words that are all CAPS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a bit of a n00b but am trying to figure out a quick way to go through my html and put a `<strong>` tag on words that are in all caps. Can this be done through CSS or will it have to be JavaScript? Either way, what would be the method? Thanks!

Comment: Definitely not possible using CSS.

Comment: Take a look at regular Expressions and the JS `replace` function. For more details you should provide information about the words and the html structure.

Comment: You can make text bold in CSS and you can Capitalize them but you cant just query using CSS to make all capitalized words bold.

Comment: Well, it's kind of funny. I'm converting notes I've been taking on HTML, CSS and JavaScript out of Evernote and converting them to HTML. So some of my notes are things like "An id is used to target SPECIFIC ELEMENTS", and I want to make "SPECIFIC ELEMENTS" bold, along with other similar text throughout the html. Does that make sense? It's basically a personal project to help me learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the Content of your element (in my example a plain div), and search with a regex for capsed words.

```
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var html = div.innerHTML;
html = html.replace(/(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)/g,"<strong>$1</strong>");
div.innerHTML = html;
```

The keypoint is the characterclass `[A-Z]` which only accepts capital letters enclosed in word borders `\b`.

[Docs for `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gLj8V/1/)

Comment: Add a jsfiddle to improve your answer :)

Comment: Oke thank you, i did the same xD  i never understand replace(), do you have a link for some explation ?

Comment: Ty sir :) this is a complete answer! i love it!